# Rails 7 how to use custom functions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a function in "common_func.js" file, and trying to call here from other file "applcation_ready.js"

My importmap is:

```
pin "common_func", to: "common_func.js", preload: true
pin "application_ready", to: "application_ready.js", preload: true
```

My application.js is:

```
import "common_func"
import "application_ready"
```

file common_func.js:

```
function f1(){
    console.log('test');
}
```

file application_ready.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    f1();
});
```

in chrome developer console i see:
`application_ready-7ea2eecd706f45c071cdfce9afd2bb46dd934efdad12e332a1ec56629c2f9f1d.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: f1 is not defined`

What's wrong?

thank you...........